# Keep text in search bar after input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to keep the text that was searched, in the text box, after hitting Enter and when showing the result.
Here's the HTML for the form, and the JS.

```
<form id="form">
                    <div class="col-md-10" id="search_container">
                        <input id="texto" type="text" name="query" class="input form-control" placeholder="Filtrar...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1" id="hide_container">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                          <label><input id="hide_ended" name="onlyActive" type="checkbox" value="false">{% trans "Ocultar terminados" %}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1" id="group_container">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                          <label><input id="group_by" name="showType" type="checkbox" value="false">{% trans "Agrupar según Tipo" %}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

The function that serialize the form is this:

```
function prepare_request() {
        url_args = "?"

        var query_str = $('#texto').val();

        if (query_str != undefined && query_str != ""){
            url_args += $('#texto').serialize();
        }

        if($('#hide_ended').is(":checked")){
            $('#hide_ended').attr('value',"true");
            url_args += $('#hide_ended').serialize();
        }

        update_list();
    }
```

update_list() function:

```
function update_list()
    {
        if (is_participants_active)
        {
            var getUrl = "{{ participants_api_url }}" + url_args;
            $.get(getUrl, function(data){
                var Data = data;
                var types=[];
                var i;
                var meetingData = Data.meeting;
                var Data = Data.participants;
                Data.sort(function(a, b){
                    if(a.name > b.name){
                        return 1;
                    }
                    if (a.name < b.name){
                        return -1;
                    }
                    return 0;
                });
```

update_list() continues, its very long, it only uses data from json.

Comment: What does update_list function do?

Comment: It makes the $.get(URL, function (Data){...}) and all of the functions

Comment: if you don't reload the page how do you lose the value from the input?

Comment: Paste the update_list body please

Comment: When you lost the input value ?

Comment: When hitting enter to make the request

Comment: Where do you call prepare_request ?

Comment: do you reload the page submitting the form?

Comment: prepare_request is called by a initialize function, that triggers when you first enter the page